# Scan through JSON object stored in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have stored the receiver of notifications as a JSON object in my DynamoDB table.
`receiver:[ { receiver_id: 'r1', receiver_name: 'a' },  { receiver_id: 'r2', receiver_name: 'b' },  { receiver_id: 'r3', receiver_name: 'c' },  ]`

I want to get the notification item if r1 is a receiver.

I tried using the FilterExpression receiver.receiver_id = 'r1' but it does not work. I want to know if there is a way to map through each set within the FilterExpression since DynamoDB shows it with indexes.

I saw some solutions that use Attr('receiver_id').eq('r1') but its in Boto3. Is there an equivalent for nodejs?

I tried doing receiver[0].receiver_id ='r1' and it worked but what if it is not at index 0?

Comment: Include more details and clarity. You've tagged this as aws-lambda, but did not mention anything lambda specific in the body of the question. You mentioned a notification, but didn't talk about what type of notification-- email? sms? something else? Expand the question and include a minimal reproducible example instead of saying "it does not work" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The notification is within the application. The FilterExpression is for the AWS Lambda function that I would use as a scan parameter for the database